# Delete all versions of an object S3 using java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I want to delete all versions of an object with a given key using software.amazon.awssdk.s3 v2.

So far I found out there is no such `deleteAllVersions(key)`, you have to get all versionIds of your object and iterate and delete each version.
The next hurdle is, there is no such `listAllVersions(key)`, only a `listAllVersions(prefix)`. So if I want to `listAllVersions("a")` of object "a" with prefix "a" as filter, I also get all version of "aa", "ab", "ac" and so on.

It is now possible to iterate an ignore all objects not having exactly key "a". But how to handle a truncated response?

How to delete all versions of an object with a specific key, including versions marked deleted?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectVersions.html

Is this not supported by Java SDK?

Comment: @Ninad Gaiwad: This is listing the versions. Part of the question is, how to get a complete list of all versions for a specific key. Since the request seems to return the objects in the order they were stored and you can't filter by key (only by prefix), I'm don't know how to be sure to get all versions of exactly "a".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ListObjectVersionsIterable` returned by `listObjectVersionsPaginator`:

```
    //Pre-filter with prefix
    ListObjectVersionsRequest listRequest = ListObjectVersionsRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).prefix(key).build();
    ListObjectVersionsIterable responses = s3Client.listObjectVersionsPaginator(listRequest);

    for (ObjectVersion objectVersion : responses.versions())
    {
        //Filter pre-filtered result
        if (objectVersion.key().equals(key))
        {
            DeleteObjectRequest deleteRequest = DeleteObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(key).versionId(versionId).build();
            DeleteObjectResponse response = s3Client.deleteObject(deleteRequest);
        }
    }
```

The Paginator will handle the calls internally: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#listObjectVersionsPaginator-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectVersionsRequest-