# How to empty Amazon S3 Bucket using AWS Java SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I was unable to find any documentation on how to empty an Amazon  S3 bucket programmatically in Java. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To ensure more ppl see your AWS questions, tag future AWS questions with "amazon-web-services".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete Amazon S3 objects using Java, you can use the [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html). To empty a bucket, first get a list of all objects in the Bucket using this code:

```
public static void listBucketObjects(S3Client s3, String bucketName ) {

       try {
            ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
                    .builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build();

            ListObjectsResponse res = s3.listObjects(listObjects);
            List<S3Object> objects = res.contents();

            for (ListIterator iterVals = objects.listIterator(); iterVals.hasNext(); ) {
                S3Object myValue = (S3Object) iterVals.next();
                System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + myValue.key());
                System.out.print("\n The object is " + calKb(myValue.size()) + " KBs");
                System.out.print("\n The owner is " + myValue.owner());

             }

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

For each object, you can delete it using this code:

```
 public static void deleteBucketObjects(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String objectName) {

    ArrayList<ObjectIdentifier> toDelete = new ArrayList<ObjectIdentifier>();
    toDelete.add(ObjectIdentifier.builder().key(objectName).build());

    try {
        DeleteObjectsRequest dor = DeleteObjectsRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .delete(Delete.builder().objects(toDelete).build())
                .build();
        s3.deleteObjects(dor);
    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

You can find these examples and many others in AWS Github here:

[Amazon S3 Java code examples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3)

Comment: And if the bucket is versioned, see [Delete all versions of an S3 object using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68035269/delete-all-versions-of-an-object-s3-using-java).

Comment: See these Javadocs - you can set the version using the Request object  -- https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/DeleteObjectRequest.html

Comment: More version info here -- https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#deleteObject-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest-